# How can I make a change in the header while I'm using the PHP include?

Tags: php

I'm using include for the header
and it's have this

```
<li><a href="arrangements.php"><span>Arrangements</span></a></li>
<li><a href="bouquet.php"><span>Build-a-Bouquet</span></a></li>
<li><a href="events.php"><span>Special Events</span></a></li>
```

and I want only any current opened page get the class="current" 
like this

```
<li class="current"><a href="bouquet.php"><span>Build-a-Bouquet</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$active = "bouquet";
include("navigation.php");
```

Navigation:

```
<li<?php if( isset($active) && $active == "arrangements") echo " class='active'";?>><span>Arrangements</span></li>
... And so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
$menus = array();
$menus['Arrangements'] = 'arrangements.php';
$menus['Build-a-Bouquet'] = 'bouquet.php';
$menus['Special Events'] = 'events.php';
?>
<ul>
<?php
$currnet_page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (! empty($menus)) {
 foreach ($menus as $menu => $menu_link) {
  $isCurrent = ($currnet_page == $menu_link) ? 'current' : '';
?>
<li class="<?php echo $isCurrent;?>"><a href="<?php echo $menu_link;?>"><span><?php echo $menu;?</span></a></li>
<?php        
  }
 }
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick example, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` can do the job.

```
<li><a href="arrangements.php"><span>Arrangements</span></a></li>
<?php
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/bouquet.php'){
    echo '<li class="current"><a href="bouquet.php"><span>Build-a-Bouquet</span></a></li>';
}else{
    echo '<li><a href="bouquet.php"><span>Build-a-Bouquet</span></a></li>';
}
?>
<li><a href="events.php"><span>Special Events</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do it. Choose the one you like:

1)
Set $current_ var you want and use:

```
<li><a<? echo isset($current_arrangements) ? 'class="current"' : ''; ?>href="arrangements.php"><span>Arrangements</span></a></li>
<li><a<? echo isset($current_bouquet) ? 'class="current"' : ''; ?>href="bouquet.php"><span>Build-a-Bouquet</span></a></li>
<li><a<? echo isset($current_special_events) ? 'class="current"' : ''; ?>href="events.php"><span>Special Events</span></a></li>
```

2) same as above but use one variable and check for its value (exactly the way Niet the Dark Absol wrote)

3) wrap it to some function

```
<?
// Echo Class If Current
function ecic($page) {
 echo eregi($page, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ? 'class="current"' : '';
}
?>


<li><a <? ecic('arrangements'); ?>href="arrangements.php"><span>Arrangements</span></a></li>
<li><a <? ecic('bouquet'); ?>href="bouquet.php"><span>Build-a-Bouquet</span></a></li>
<li><a <? ecic('events'); ?>href="events.php"><span>Special Events</span></a></li>
```

BTW: In most common PHP configurations you can use just `<?` instead of `<?php`.

Comment: `eregi` is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. For this example you can use `stristr`